# Apache 2.4.12 keeps loosing connection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.12 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

It has been running for the past year with no problems. However, in the past couple of weeks it has been going away. and the only was to bring it backup quick is to restart the Apache service.

When I look at the error.log file I see the following repeated too many times.

> [Thu Feb 11 09:12:30.404473 2016] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 6512:tid 2008]
>   (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341:
>   winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

Following guidance from this blog [Apache 2.4 => winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=21352)

I have added the following lines to my httpd.conf file, but the issue still happens

```
ThreadsPerChild 150

AcceptFilter http none
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

How can I correct this issue?

Any idea why would it just start happening now?

**UPDATE**
I came accross this artical http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=20474
I added the workaround to my httpd-ssl.conf file "I don't know if this will solve my problem" I will update this question in couple of days it I encounter the issues again or not

```
ProxyRequests Off
Win32DisableAcceptEx
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP off

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1/
```

**Updated Again**
The above solution did not fix the problem. I still have the same problem